# How do I get the frequency of repeated fields that contain some value?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Supposed I have a data set that looks like this

```
{"id":15,"classification":"goth","categories":["blackLipstick","hotTopic"]}
{"id":14,"classification":"goth","categories":["drinking","girls","hotTopic"]}
{"id":13,"classification":"jock","categories":["basketball","chicharones","fooball","girls","pop","pregnant","sports","starTrek","tortilla","tostada"]}
{"id":12,"classification":"geek","categories":["academics","cacahuates","computers","glasses","papas","physics","programming","ps4","science"]}
{"id":11,"classification":"geek","categories":["cacahuates","fajitas","math","pregnant","raves","xbox"]}
{"id":10,"classification":"goth","categories":["cutting"]}
{"id":9,"classification":"geek","categories":["cafe","chalupa","chimichangas","manson","physics","pollo","tostada"]}
{"id":8,"classification":"jock","categories":["basketball","chalupa","enchurrito","piercings","running","sports"]}
{"id":7,"classification":"geek","categories":["aguacate","blackLipstick","computers","fajitas","fooball","glasses","lifting","outdoors","physics","pollo","pregnant","ps4"]}
{"id":6,"classification":"none","categories":["brocode","girls","raves","tacos"]}
{"id":5,"classification":"goth","categories":["blackLipstick","blackShirts","drugs","mole","piercings","tattoos","tortilla"]}
{"id":4,"classification":"jock","categories":["girls","tattoos"]}
{"id":3,"classification":"goth","categories":["girls"]}
{"id":2,"classification":"none","categories":["cutting","enchurrito","fooball","pastel","pregnant","tattoos","vampires"]}
{"id":1,"classification":"goth","categories":["cacahuates","cutting","drugs","empanadas","frijoles","manson","nachos","outdoors","piercings","tattoos"]}
{"id":0,"classification":"geek","categories":["pollo","pop","programming","science"]}
```

How do I write a query to where I can say
"If someone has category 'math' what other categories do they often have?"

For this data set I can write something like this to tell me what goths, geeks and jocks like most.

```
SELECT classification, categories, count(categories) C 
FROM [xx.stereotypes] group by classification
, categories ORDER BY C DESC LIMIT 1000
```

But in my real dataset I don't have the classification field. I want a query that could make help me create classifications like "goth", "jock" or "geek".

For example how do I say select all the counts of the categories where categories contains "math", this only selects math

```
SELECT categories, count(categories) C FROM [xx.stereotypes]
where categories CONTAINS "math" group by categories ORDER
BY C DESC LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I say select all the counts of the categories where categories
>   contains "math"

```
SELECT categories, COUNT(1) AS weight
FROM [xx.stereotypes]
OMIT RECORD IF NOT SOME(categories = 'math')
GROUP BY categories
ORDER BY weight DESC
```

> How do I write a query to where I can say "If someone has category
>   'math' what other categories do they often have?"

```
SELECT category, related_category, weight 
FROM (
  SELECT category, related_category, COUNT(1) AS weight 
  FROM (
    SELECT a.id AS id, a.categories AS category, b.categories AS related_category 
    FROM (FLATTEN([xx.stereotypes], categories)) AS a
    JOIN (FLATTEN([xx.stereotypes], categories)) AS b
    ON a.id = b.id
    HAVING category != related_category
  )
  GROUP BY category, related_category
) 
WHERE category = 'math'
ORDER BY category, weight DESC, related_category
```

> I want a query that could make help me create classifications

Below simplified way to assign classification to each id

```
SELECT id, category AS classification 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    x.id AS id, y.category AS category, SUM(weight) AS rate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rate DESC) AS pos
  FROM (FLATTEN(xx.stereotypes, categories)) AS x
  JOIN (
    SELECT category, related_category, COUNT(1) AS weight 
    FROM (
      SELECT a.id AS id, a.categories AS category, b.categories AS related_category 
      FROM (FLATTEN([xx.stereotypes], categories)) AS a
      JOIN (FLATTEN([xx.stereotypes], categories)) AS b
      ON a.id = b.id
    )
    GROUP BY category, related_category 
  ) AS y
  ON x.categories = y.related_category
  GROUP BY 1, 2 
)
WHERE pos = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: You are awesome Mikhail!